# Replace excess text with elipses (...)

Tags: javascript, css, html, overflow

The snippet pretty much explains what I want. How do I do this with html5/css/js?

```css
body {
  background-color: teal;
  color: orange;
  font-family: verdana;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
#song {
  background-color: turquoise;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;
}
.button {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid orange 1px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px pink;
  background-color: cyan;
  color: white;
  cursor: hand;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.button:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
#play {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#play img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>REPLACE THIS:</h1>
<!--original code-->
<div id="song">
  <button class="button" id="play">
    <img src="http://lizkhoo.com/content/play-icon.png">
  </button>
  <h1 class="title">I am a really really really long song title</h1>
</div>
<!--end original code-->

<h1>WITH THIS:</h1>
<div id="song">
  <button class="button" id="play">
    <img src="http://lizkhoo.com/content/play-icon.png">
  </button>
  <h1 class="title">I am a really...</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't understand the question, please be clearer

Answer (score 1):

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/4kayztrs/

I think I know what you are talking about but not really clear. Try this out.

```
.title {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 210px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You can change the width until you get the right styling you want.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might work.

```
function shorten(text, maxLength) {
    var ret = text;
if (ret.length > maxLength) {
    ret = ret.substr(0,maxLength-3) + "...";
}
    return ret;
}
```

OR:

textoverflow:ellipsis

in CSS will accomplish this also.  sometimes it is better to use CSS because it will automatically do it.  But its your choice.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do the trick :

```js
var nbCharMax = 12 // Max number of char you want after text shortening

var longText = document.getElementById("longText");
longText.innerHTML = longText.innerHTML.substring(0, nbCharMax) + "...";
```

```html
<div id="longText">I'm a really really long text</div>
```